# how to update a field conditionally in firebase

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I'm updating a record and decrementing a value but I would like to do it only if certain condition is met. Can I do it in a single operation or I will need to get the data first and then update it?

```
  return db
    .collection("users")
    .doc(userId)
    .update({
      daysLeft: firebase.firestore.FieldValue !== "" && firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(-1) // something like this?
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible with Firestore to do this in a single operation like a SQL "update where" statement.  Instead, you will have to get the document, check the value, then update the value if the condition is met.

You can perform the operation atomically with a [transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions), which can do the get, check, and update without conflict with other transactions trying to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

This sort of operation has to be done with a transaction, this is because Firestore does not support an overhead server that manages this kind of iterative logic.
A transaction requires you to make both a read and a write, this is typically *"read a value from the server and write the changes back"*

An example:

```js
var sfRef = db.collection("users").doc(userId);

return db.runTransaction((transaction) => {
    return transaction.get(sfRef).then((sfDoc) => {
        if (!sfDoc.exists) {
            throw "Document does not exist!";
        }
        var daysRemaining = sfDoc.data().daysLeft >0?sfDoc.data().daysLeft - 1:0;
        transaction.update(sfDocRef, { daysLeft: daysRemaining});
    });
}).then(() => {
    console.log("Transaction successfully committed!");
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log("Transaction failed: ", error);
});
```